# how to check "Success" key value in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(webpath).responseJSON
{   response in
    //here check success key ???
}
```

my json response contains

```
{Message = "some message";
Success = True;}
```

how to take Success key directly from response and check in if condition ? that it is true or false

Comment: I believe you can just do  if (response["Success"]){}; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you have to get the `Result` object from the response. It is an enum that can either be `success` or `failure`.
2. Then you have to cast the `Any` object returned from the `success` value as a dictionary.
3. Now you can simply access the property by its key.

Like following:

```
Alamofire.request(webpath).responseJSON { response in
    guard case .success(let rawJSON) = response.result else {
        // handle failure
        return
    }

    // rawJSON is your JSON response in an `Any` object.
    // make a dictionary out of it:
    guard let json = rawJSON as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }

    // now you can access the value for "Success":
    guard let successValue = json["Success"] as? String else {
        // `Success` is not a String
        return
    }

    if successValue == "True" {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is right but after this i have to check , if json["Success"] == "True" , how to check ?

Comment: @Dharini I updated the answer if the value of "Success" is a String.

Answer (score 1):

**You can check as follows:**

```
let statusCheck = dicObj["Success"] as! Int

if statusCheck == 1{
    println("Success")
}
else{
    println("Failure")
}
```

Comment: im storing response.result.value in dicobj as string in this case    let statusCheck = dicObj["Success"] as! Int not working

Comment: let swiftyJsonVar = response.result.value!
if let dicObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSDictionary {

}

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve like this.

```
if let result = response.result.value {
     let JSON = result as! [String:Any]
      if JSON["success"] == 1
     {
         print("success")
      }

}
```

Comment: if JSON["success"] == 1 displaying error like " Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int' "

Comment: try like this if success is bool value `if JSON["success"] as Bool == true {print("success")}`. if success value is string `if JSON["success"] as String == "true" {print("success")}`